# I want add in database data, that consists of few forms

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

This method adds inserted in form data in database. But it reads only first form,  reads from it and writes the same data for all days and times. It don't see other forms that consists lower. How should I change this method?

```
  def addPoints = Action.async {
implicit request =>
  PointForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errorForm => Future.successful(Ok(views.html.index(errorForm, Seq.empty[Point], days, times))),
    data => {
      for (d <- days) {
        for (t <- times) {
          if (data.subject != null) {
            val newPoint = Point(0, data.subject, d, data.groupName, data.kind, formatTime(t), data.teacher, data.auditorium)
            PointService.addPoint(newPoint)
          }
        }
      }
      PointService.listAllPoints.map(res => Redirect(routes.PointController.index()))
    }
  )
```

}

This is html code for displaying these forms, as you can see they are in cycle, so they are displaying d*t times. How can I gather data from it regarding that they have same names?

```
@(pointform: Form[models.PointFormData], points: Seq[models.Point], days: Seq[String], times: Seq[String])(implicit request: RequestHeader)
    @main() {
        <form id="point-data-form" role="form" action='@routes.PointController.addPoints()' method="post" class="form-horizontal" align="center" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" id="groupName" name="groupName" value="" placeholder="Name of Group" class="form-control input-lg" required>
            @for(d <- days) {
                <h3>@d</h3>
                @for(t <- times) {
                    @t
                    <div> <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control input-lg" >
                        <input type="text" id="kind" name="kind" value="" placeholder="Type" class="form-control input-lg" >
                        <input type="text" id="teacher" name="teacher" value="" placeholder="Teacher" class="form-control input-lg" >
                        <input type="number" id="auditorium" name="auditorium" value="" placeholder="Auditorium" class="form-control input-lg" >
                    </div>
                }
            }
            <div class="form-actions controls ynt-btn-xlarge">
                <button type=submit class="btn btn-primary ynt-btn-orange">Add</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Full answer coming later, but for now you should change the ´id´ on the inputs in the loop or you'll have duplicate IDs.

Comment: .addPoint actually don`t read IDs. I use slick library and it has it's own ID that creates or reads last value and autoincrements. I't just formality for constructor. I think that's not the point, cause it adds point immediately after its creating.

Comment: I'm not talking about the server side - IDs should be unique within a document; this is just a side observation.